# Alloy Collection and Models for POST data

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm not new to Titanium by any means, but I am quite new to Alloy and I am trying to grasp the concept of Collections and Models.

My first view/controller is a login screen so naturally I need to submit a username and password to an API. I found this and am able to successfully retrieve an example JSON feed: https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restapi

In my models folder, I have a model called `Login` (or is it, I have a collection?)

```
exports.definition = {  
    config: {
        "URL": "http://example.com/services/user/login",
        "debug": 0, 
        "adapter": {
            "type": "restapi",
            "collection_name": "Login",
            "idAttribute": "id"
        },
        "headers": {},
        "parentNode": "feed" //your root node
    },      
    extendModel: function(Model) {      
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {});
        return Model;
    },  
    extendCollection: function(Collection) {        
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {});
        return Collection;
    }       
};
```

My controller calls this model via:

```
var login = Alloy.createCollection('Login');
login.fetch({ 
  success : function()
  {
    _.each(login.models, function(element, index, list)
    {
      //-- handle the response
    });
  },
  error : function()
  {
    Ti.API.error('xhr error!');
  }
});
```

My question, which isn't clear on the aforementioned link, is how to POST data to that model to send to the API. Like I said, I need to send a username and password.

Comment: if this question is specific to the module, why don't you post an issue https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restapi/issues you might get a response quicker

Answer (score 1):

i have some pretty thorough examples of this.

but the basic premise is that you need to extend a user model to support the login function, not do it in a collection.

See complete example here https://github.com/aaronksaunders/AppC-Alloy-Book/blob/master/app/models/user.js

Although this model is for ACS, the basic pattern remains the same

```
  extendModel : function(Model) {
       _.extend(Model.prototype, {
          login : function(_login, _password, _callback) {}
       }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron for this share. I also needed this. Great fan and follower of your posts.